# Fancy Headers (fancyhdr) How to create running header with Subsection Numbers?

Tags: header-footer

What is the syntax to specify the right header in the fancyhdr package (though maybe there's another solution) so it prints the starting subsection number on each page? (Beginning and ending would be great too.

I tried this:

```
\rhead{\subsection}
```

But this didn't work.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}%{article}
\usepackage{geometry}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{\footnotesize{Article titles are not part of the law}}
\chead{}
%\rhead{\subsection}  %% Didn't work
\rhead {Part \thepart} %% works, but shows up on ToC page, would   like to remove
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\footnotesize{version 0.5}}

\begin{document}

\part{General Provisions} \index{General Provisions}


\subsection{Article $[$1$]$ Definitions} \index{Definitions}
The following phrases and expressions, wherever mentioned in the   

\end{document}
```

---

Here's a picture of the ToC with the word 'Article' before each article and the description of same.

If there's another way to accomplish this other than

```
\subsection{Article $[$1$]$ Definitions} \index{Definitions}
```

(and I'm sure there is)

I'd like to know.

[image: ToC Pic]

---

[image]

"Part V" in the running header isn't optimal, I'd rather have the subsection numbers--which would be a range, but with the figures in math mode I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Try `\rhead{\thesection}`

Comment: That worked. So does {\thesubsection}. Unfortunately, the subsection numbers had to be entered manually in math mode, so they're not reflected. I could use "Parts" though, and {\thepart} worked as well. Make your comment into an answer so I can check it.

Comment: What do you mean by *"the subsection numbers had to be entered manually in math mode"*? This doesn't sound like a regular solution. If you add a small complete document to your question showing what you want to achieve (and which setup you use) I probably find a better one.

Comment: Added a MWE to show the subsection numbers in math mode. The \thepart solution worked, except that it is showing up on the ToC. If I delete the word "Part" then it's not clear what the Roman numerals I, II, III mean on the page.

Comment: The geometry package is added so I could squeeze three lines onto a single page later in the document. I added it to the MWE in case it's interfering with fancyhdr.

Comment: The reason why I entered the Subsection numbers in this fashion was to have greater control over them in typesetting a text where sometimes the numbers are repeated--and there's no way to correct.

Comment: The more you describe your motivation the more I get confused, like with your reason for using math mode (which I do not get). Do you really want to have double numbering, on the part page (Part I Part 1 Genera provision) as well as with section headings (0.0.1 Article [1])?  In your sample document, do you skip the intermediate levels `\chapter` and `\section`  just to make the example shorter, or do you intend to use `\subsecton` directly below `\part`, without `\chapter`s and `\sections`? The fact that you want to put the subsection numbers into the running head points into this direction.

Comment: I suggest that you take a step backward, define/describe (i) which section levels you want to use, (ii) how they should be formatted in the text (including the numbering), (iiI) how they should be formatted in the toc, (iv) what should go into the running header, as well as any further requirements. Then we can look for the most adequate solution.

Comment: When you start composing the document, you do not know if there will be any errors in the text--which cannot be altered--so that article numbers are repeated. Let's say that the articles were numbered, 1, 2, 3...50, 50, 51, 52, 53...(assuming only one error). This would mean, if the LaTeX internal numbering system were used, that every article after the first 50 would be improperly numbered--and fixed manually. It's an unusual use case, but a real one.

Comment: I edited the MWE to remove \part{Part 1}. That was an artifact of creating a MWE. Unnumbered chapters are used to set-off sections in various parts. Originally the subsections were sections, but the section titles were too large, so I made them subsections. I wish I could get the subsections into the running heads--that didn't work, but I'll try again. The problem is not which section levels "I want to use": I'm not writing the text--(except for the subsection titles)--but typesetting it.

Comment: *"This would mean, if the LaTeX internal numbering system were used, that every article after the first 50 would be improperly numbered"* Does this mean that you can't use LaTeX's `\label` and `\ref` commands to keep the numbering automatic *and* consistent? Are there numbers in the headings that are referenced from outside the document that have to stay fixed, or is your only concern to keep the document consistent? Sorry for keeping asking questions, but without understanding what you actually want it is difficult to propose an adequate solution.

Comment: The numbering must reflect the errors in an external document. So in the example above, where the error is two Art. 50's, the error must be repeated and not corrected. Yesterday I found that two sub-subsections repeated the same text. Fortunately this is not a numbering issue. I am not familiar with \label or \ref but I will look them up. I was thinking of using tr (or sed or awk) to substitute \section{name of article) for the math mode to see what would happen, but I lose the word "Article" and I'm mulling over whether that would be acceptable. Probably not. The way the ToC looks now is fine